# How do I return three variables?

Tags: function, loops, haskell, recursion

My task is to identify on what arguments `x`, `y`, and `z` a function `tresor` will return `True`. I want to iterate through recursion every variable from `0` to `100`, similarly to the following imperative loop:

```
for z = 0 to 100:
  for y = 0 to 100:
    for x = 0 to 100:
      if tresor x y z:
        return (x,y,z)
```

So first I would like to check all `x` from 0 to 100, then if x = 100, set x = 0 and y+1 and again x to 100, and so on for z…

However, I don't know how to return `x,y,z` separately.

Here is my code:

```
crack tresor =     
    crackthe tresor 0 0 0

crackthe tresor x y z =    
    if tresor x y z == False
        then if x < 100 
            then crackthe tresor (x+1) (y) (z)
            else if x == 100 && y < 100
                then crackthe tresor (x-100) (y+1) (z)
                else if y == 100 && x == 100 && z < 100
                    then crackthe tresor (x-100) (y-100) (z+1)
                    else (x+y+z)
        else (x+y+z)
```

Comment: Do you really want recursion? It seems so much easier with a list comprehension in this case: `head [(x + y + z) | x <- [0..99], y <- [0..99], z <- [0..99], tresor x y z]`. Although this doesn't do exactly the same as you intended. Also, I suggest you to return a `Maybe (Int, Int, Int)` instead, after all, the tresor might have a broken lock.

Comment: Do you need to return the sum or instead want the triple `(x,y,z)` ?

Comment: If you want to fully scan `x` values before incrementing `y`, you can adapt @Zeta's code reversing the generators: `head [(x + y + z) | z <- [0..100], y <- [0..100], x <- [0..100], tresor x y z]`

Comment: yeah unfortunately i need the recursion task, because i want to improve it! Moreover thanks for your replies! and yeah i want to return x, y, z seperated and clearly :)

Comment: @satubus: Your title states that you want to to this "parallely". However, there is no parallelism in your code at all. Do you _really_ want parallelism?

Comment: @Zeta i didn't know how to be exactlier, i just want to iterate through recursion every single combination of x y z values, to hit the true variable for the function!

Comment: @satubus: Well, your question seems like you want to return `x,y,z` separately. Is this just about returning a tuple? By the way, you probably want to use English function names instead of German ones when you're on an international site.

Comment: @Zeta Yep! Oh your right, I should do that! Any idea how I can return x,y,z seperately?

Comment: Use `(x,y,z)` (with the parentheses included) instead of `x+y+z`.

Comment: based on @chi s two superb answers you should just use `head [(x, y, z) | z <- [0..100], y <- [0..100], x <- [0..100], tresor x y z]` ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig yes i know

Comment: @chi you should probably make this into an answer ;)

Comment: well, now i get this error, and i really dont know the meaning : "No instance for (show(t0->t10->t20->(t0,t10,t20)))) arising froma use of print In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Comment: You are trying to print a function in GHCi: supply all the arguments to print the result.

Comment: @Chi well, i thought i did so... now I am confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implementation that will look a lot like your imperative loop is the following:

```
crackthe tresor = do         -- function crackthe tresor:
  z <- [0..100]              --   for z = 0 to 100:
  y <- [0..100]              --     for y = 0 to 100:
  x <- [0..100]              --       for x = 0 to 100:
  guard (tresor x y z)       --         if tresor x y z:
  return (x, y, z)           --           return (x,y,z)
```

This relies on the fact that, in `do` notation for lists, `<-` is like a loop over all the list elements, and `guard` is like `break` if the condition isn't satisfied.

Comment: Note: the imperative variant wasn't originally in the author's question. But since he accepted your answer, I guess he's fine with it, although it isn't recursive at all.

Comment: @Zeta Yeah, I just now saw the "through recursion" bit. Maybe that's just a terminology mistake by the author (based on the frequent misunderstanding that "in Haskell you must use recursion to iterate"), or maybe the author is going to learn a lesson about copying homework solutions blindly from the internets. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can return three variables by using a tuple of three numbers instead of a single number, as in:

```
crack tresor = (5,2,13)
```

Answer (score 2):

step-by-step solution:

open your favorite editor and paste in this:

```
module Tresor where

crack tresor =     
    crackthe tresor 0 0 0

crackthe tresor x y z =    
    if tresor x y z == False
        then if x < 100 
            then crackthe tresor (x+1) (y) (z)
            else if x == 100 && y < 100
                then crackthe tresor (x-100) (y+1) (z)
                else if y == 100 && x == 100 && z < 100
                    then crackthe tresor (x-100) (y-100) (z+1)
                    else (x,y,z)
        else (x,y,z)
```

this is just your code with `(x,y,z)` instead of `(x+y+z)`

Now save it as "tresor.hs", start ghci and load it with `:l tresor.hs` you should now be able to do something like this:

```
λ> crack (\ x y z -> 2*x + y - z -5 == 0)
(2,1,0)
```

as you can see for the `tresor` function `2*x+y-z-5==0` the first found solution will be `(2,1,0)` meaning `x=2, y=1, z=0` which works ;)

### simpler approach

is to use list comprehensions as mentioned by @chi

```
crackThe :: (Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool) -> (Int, Int, Int)
crackThe tresor = head [(x, y, z) | z <- [0..100], y <- [0..100], x <- [0..100], tresor x y z]
```

#### usage

```
λ> crackThe (\ x y z -> 2*x + y - z -5 == 0)
(2,1,0)
```

Comment: thanks alot! Now I get a parse error on "module tresor where" :S

Comment: @satubus Make it uppercase as in `Tresor`.

Comment: nvm lol i found the problem! I was always entering "crackthe tresor1 "instead of crack tresor1, so there i was fooling myself lol... thank you all for your great support :)

Comment: @chi: He can make it up if he publishes another Church encoding kata on Codewars.

Comment: @Zeta me? Not till the thing is fixed - but I did not look there for quite some time ;9